# how eliminate orphans when filtering in RDL SSRS

Tags: filter, ssrs-2012, conditional-formatting, rdl

I filtered my report based on a certain expression. Those that do not meet the criteria that I put in my IFF expression are then filtered and those that do meet it, are shown in my report. My report is multiple pages, so when the filtering happens, some records are left alone on a page, and are not moved up. This leaves a lot of whitespace, and I would like to get rid of that.

On page 1, there will be 2 images/records, with space for one more
On page 2, there will be only 1 image/record that would fit on page one, but doesn't move up 
on page 3, there will be only 1 image/record that would fit on page 2 but stays on page 1 etc...

my Keeptogether value is set to true, however this does not help. I have been trying to find something that will keep these records together when filter happens, so that the number of pages is minimal.

If someone could help, I'd really appreciate it.

Regards
Jay

Comment: Have you tried changing the Visibility property to True for the textbox or the specific control you want to remove.   Just use the same criteria in the IFF expression for the Visibility property.

Answer (score 0):

Are you "filtering" via the Visibility in Properties? Because such way will just hide, rather than rule out, the records/images you don't want. If that's the case, try filtering via the Filter in the Properties of the tablix (or Groups, if it applys to your case). But I think the best way is to do the filter job in you data set query, because that will provide you best performance.

Answer (score 0):

So i resolved my problem by adding my IFF expression that I orginially had in the visibility option to the filter by expression option. Everything now moves up and the extra white space that was there before is gone.

Thank you for your help!! :)